# Closing unneeded branches in Hg but backdating that

Tags: mercurial

I have a lot of projects that are started and soon closed on top of my framework. I often have to do fixes for them. So we decided that it will be nice to maintain a separate named branch for each such project.

The problem is that I want to close the branches when the projects are done, but the teams that work on the projects are remote and I usually do not know the status of the project. I can ask the team every month what projects were closed, but the projects are usually very short, and we have 5-10 of them till the end of the month. I do not want to bother them and ask each day.

If I just close them each 1st day of the month, I receive this picture:

[image: Example of how Workbench shows the closed branches]

Which is a bit ugly. How could I close the branch, but put the close marker just after the branch in the tree and not now? I'm probably looking for a way to change the history, but to not rebase, but rather change the "Revision number" and "Created date" of the changeset so it would be sorted differently.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just aesthetics, there is no value in changing the way it looks. A few days in the month and you won't see that pattern again until next month.

If you really want to do it anyway, know that the repo does not care about the date of the commit, it just cares about when it was added to it, either from commit directly or from push/pull. So the idea is to reorder how they are added. You do not have to change the history, just rearrange the changesets.

The method would be to clone the repo to the initial commit, and pull one closed branch after the other. It would look like this:

```
hg clone <repo> -r1
hg pull -b <closed-branch-1>
hg pull -b <closed-branch-2>
...
hg pull
```

The last pull is to retrieve the remaining changesets in active branches.

After that, if you are satisfied with how it looks, you can replace your main repo with this new one.